# Docker Desktop on macOS keeps saying "read-only file system"

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I have Docker Desktop installed on a 2018 Mac Mini (macOS 13.1), and I am running a GitLab CI Runner on this machine, with the following configuration:

```
concurrent = 8
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Mac-Mini - Docker Desktop"
  url = "https://gitlab.example.com"
  token = "REDACTED"
  executor = "docker"
  environment = ["container=docker"]
  [runners.docker]
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Once or twice a week, my builds start failing with errors like this:

```
Error response from daemon: open /var/lib/docker/containers/SOME_ID/SOME_OTHER_ID-json.log: read-only file system
```

This happens for all containers on the machine.

Restart Docker Desktop sometimes fixes the problem, and sometimes a full reboot of the computer is required.

Why would the Docker filesystem suddenly become read-only, and how can I stop this from happening again?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to do the next:

- check filesystem for corruption;
- check that you have free space on your system disk;
- run `dmesg` in terminal and maybe you will see the issue.

Also check [permission recomendations from docker](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/permission-requirements/)